# How to show list to Tree View in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, treeview

We have data in an array looking like:

```
["Root1","Root1-Child1", "Root1-Child2", "Root1-Child1-Child1.1", "Root2", "Root2-Child1"]
```

How can we recreate this in a tree like

> [image]

We have tried doing this using for loop, but were not able to get the expected results

Comment: Share your code what you have done and what component you have used for tree view? If possible try to create demo on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You may need to edit your question based on these guidelines. Please don't add screenshots from external sources.